# adb shell am broadcast - BroadcastReceiver throws nullpointer

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sms, broadcastreceiver, adb

I'm trying to launch this command:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED --es sms_body "TEXTTEXTTEXT"   -n com.example.name/.receivers.SmsReceiver
```

And this code throws null pointer exception:

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
...

private Context mContext;
private Intent mIntent;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext = context;
    mIntent = intent;

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(Const.ACTION_SMS_RECEIVED)) {
        String address = "", str = "";

        SmsMessage[] msgs = getMessagesFromIntent(mIntent);

        ...

    }
}

public static SmsMessage[] getMessagesFromIntent (Intent intent){
        Object[] messages = (Object[]) intent.getSerializableExtra("pdus");
        byte[][] pduObjs = new byte[messages.length][];

        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            pduObjs[i] = (byte[]) messages[i];
        }

        byte[][] pdus = new byte[pduObjs.length][];
        int pduCount = pdus.length;
        SmsMessage[] msgs = new SmsMessage[pduCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < pduCount; i++) {
            pdus[i] = pduObjs[i];
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdus[i]);
        }
        return msgs;
}
```

}

And here is the console output:

```
12-30 15:48:34.724  26032-26032/com.example.name E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.name, PID: 26032
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.name.receivers.SmsReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2567)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.name.receivers.SmsReceiver.getMessagesFromIntent(SmsReceiver.java:60)
            at com.example.name.receivers.SmsReceiver.onReceive(SmsReceiver.java:30)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2552)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Now, here is the tricky part. 
My code inside SmsReceiver works for normal SMS messages. When I try to "simulate" this problem, I get this error. Probalby I mixed up something with adb command. I tried to fix it myself, but no luck. Do you have any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have any idea what I did wrong?

You are sending a broadcast with a string extra named `sms_body`. Your code is not using that. Your code is using a `Serializable` extra named `pdus`.

> When I try to "simulate" this problem, I get this error.

Use the Emulator Control tab in DDMS, or perhaps the emulator console (e.g., `telnet localhost 5554`), to send simulated SMS messages to an emulator.

Or, move your SMS-processing logic into a Java class that you can test using JUnit.

Comment: Yes, I used pdus part, still no luck.

About using emulator... Is there a way to use an external device? (talking about unittests - unfortunately I'm working on other persons project and I'm not full comfortable making changes in the code, right now I'm just "poking around")

Comment: @user1812056: "Is there a way to use an external device?" -- not using DDMS or the emulator console.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong: there is no way to "feed" my BroadcastReceiver on my physical device with command similar to what I posted?

Comment: @user1812056: I do not know how you would, on the command line, create the `pdus` extra, as it is not a string, but rather a `Serializable` object.