# Do we need a sim in testing device to run the sms sending app using sms manager in android studio

Tags: android

My code is below,I have created a button to send sms,on Clicking that button the user should send message to the number.the message was not received.But I don't have sim in that testing device.Is it because of that I didn't get output.Can anyone please help me in this to send messages.

```
btnmsg2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                String name=etname.getText().toString();
                String message=etmessage.getText().toString();
                String Phoneno="96891961976";
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("+96891961976",null, message, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage().toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Also I have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />`
in manifest file

Comment: Of course you need a sim to send sms

Comment: If not then how are you expecting it to work!  Its obvious. SMS does not work with mobile data  :)

Comment: Is my coding part is correct?

Comment: yes your coding part is correct @Sowmya .

Comment: pls refere this solution
[simulate sms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537307/simulating-sms-on-android-devices-when-developing) .